# 8086, copying data from one list to another

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

```
;program starts

TABLE  DB 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0   
TABLE1 DB ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?   

MOV SI, OFFSET TABLE  
MOV DI, OFFSET TABLE1

MOV AL, [SI]
MOV [DI], AL

MOV AL, [SI+1]
MOV [DI+4], AL

MOV AL, [SI+2]
MOV [DI+8], AL

MOV AL, [SI+3]
MOV [DI+12], AL

MOV AL, [SI+4]
MOV [DI+1], AL

;program ends
```

Here's a simple code that copies data from 'TABLE' to 'TABLE1'. As I run this program in emu8086, the value [SI] gets displayed in the AL register (MOV AL, [SI]). The values in 'TABLE' thus are shown in the AL register and should logically be same. But when the line 'MOV AL, [SI+1]' is executed, the AL register shows 4 instead of 2. If I replace this second element with 3, the Al register shows 6 instead of 3. Can anyone explain the reason behind this event and how to counter it?

Comment: What's the value of `DS`? Is it set to the segment where the arrays are located? Does the program work if you add `ORG 100h` at the top of the file?

Comment: `;program starts` into data table? That would probably lead to some weird behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assembly programs for EMU require some structure that is missing in your code :

```
.model small                 ◄■■■ PROGRAM SIZE.
.stack 100h                  ◄■■■ STACK SEGMENT DECLARATION.
.data                        ◄■■■ DATA SEGMENT DECLARATION.

TABLE  DB 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0   
TABLE1 DB ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?   

.code                        ◄■■■ CODE SEGMENT DECLARATION.

mov ax, @data                ◄■■■ INITIALIZATION
mov ds, ax                   ◄■■■ OF DATA SEGMENT.

MOV SI, OFFSET TABLE  
MOV DI, OFFSET TABLE1

MOV AL, [SI]
MOV [DI], AL

MOV AL, [SI+1]
MOV [DI+4], AL

MOV AL, [SI+2]
MOV [DI+8], AL

MOV AL, [SI+3]
MOV [DI+12], AL

MOV AL, [SI+4]
MOV [DI+1], AL

mov ax, 4c00h                ◄■■■ FINISH PROGRAM PROPERLY.
int 21h
```

With this structure your code works (I replaced some values of `TABLE` for testing purposes).

Comment: @protonmail, if this answer is useful you may click the checkmark to accept it (that's how you reward people's effort).